# Equivalent of cURL Post request call in rails model or controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, box-api

The following line of code works fine when I call it from the terminal. I want to run the equivalent of it from within my Rails app to refresh my access_token field (see [Using the Access and Refresh Tokens](http://developers.box.com/oauth/)):

```
curl https://api.box.com/oauth2/token \
-d 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={valid refresh token}&client_id={your_client_id}&client_secret={your_client_secret}' \
-X POST
```

Assuming I have all the params available, how would I post this request from a model or controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing the following code in my Authentication model to get a refreshed Box OAuth token. That way I can do something like `User.authentication.find_by_provider('box').refresh!` if it's expired (which I check each time I call the Box API through the `token` method).

```
  require 'uri'
  require 'net/http'

  def refresh!
    case self.provider
    when 'box'
      url = "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token"
      uri = URI(url)
      params = {}
      params["grant_type"] = "refresh_token"
      params["refresh_token"] = self.refresh_token
      params["client_id"] = APP_CONFIG['box_client_id']
      params["client_secret"] = APP_CONFIG['box_client_secret']
      res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
               req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
               req.set_form_data(params)
               response = http.request(req)
            end
      res_json = JSON.parse(res.body)
      self.refresh_token = res_json["refresh_token"]
      self.oauth_token = res_json["access_token"]
      self.expires_at = Time.now.to_i + res_json["expires_in"].to_i
      self.save      
    end
  end

  def fresh_token
    case self.provider
    when 'box'
      self.refresh! if self.is_expired? && self.is_refreshable?
      self.oauth_token
    else
      self.oauth_token
    end
  end


  def is_refreshable?
    case self.provider
    when 'box'
      Time.now < self.updated_at + 14.days ? true : false
    else
      nil
    end
  end


  def is_expired?
    case self.provider
    when 'box'
      Time.now.to_i > self.expires_at ? true : false
    else
      false      
    end
  end
```

For instance, to get a Box user profile I would do:

```
  def profile
    token = self.fresh_token

    case self.provider
    when 'box'
      profile = JSON.parse(open("https://api.box.com/2.0/users/me?access_token=#{token}").read)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```rb
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("https://api.box.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=#{valid_refresh_token}&client_id=#{your_client_id}&client_secret=#{your_client_secret}"))
```

Comment: This returns `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)`. I've also tried `Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, params)` (with uri = `URI.parse("https://api.box.com/oauth2/token")` and params is a hash with my keys and values), which returns `#<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true> `